# How to get word inside brackets in string (java)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string variable, and I want to get the words inside the brackets. Then, I want to store the words inside the bracket into another variable. Last I want to free the first string variable from the words inside the bracket.

Here is an Example:

```
String a = "nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja  [Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]";
```

I want the output become like this:

```
String b = "nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja";
String c = "[Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.+)(\\[.+\\])").matcher(a);
if (m.matches())
{
    String b = m.group(1), c = m.group(2);
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split the input string according to the space followed by an opening square bracket.

```
String a = "nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja  [Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]";
String tok[]= a.split("\\s+(?=\\[)");
String b = tok[0];
String c = tok[1];
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

**Output:**

```
nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja
[Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)\s*(\[[^\]]*\])
```

Try this.Grab the cpatures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/7

Answer (score -1):

Use following

```
String a = "nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja  [Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]";
String tok[]=a.split(" \\[");
for(String test:tok){
  System.out.println(test);
}
```

**Output :**

```
nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja 
Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja  [Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]";

    String strBeforeBracket = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("[") - 1);
    String strInBracket = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("["),
            str.lastIndexOf("]") + 1);
    System.out.println("String outside bracket  : " + strBeforeBracket);
    System.out.println("String in bracket   : " + strInBracket);
}
```

**Output :**

```
String outside bracket  : nemenin yang ngebet sangat ingin belanja 
String in bracket       : [Mon Sep 22 13:46:19 ICT 2014]
```